# C++ writing operation still ongoing when program is done

Tags: visual-c++

Platform: Windows
Now I am trying to split data into two different files. And at the end of the coding I calculate the total time.

```
CcaWriter_destroy(vehCaptureFile);
CcaWriter_destroy(gpsCaptureFile);
CcaFile_destroy(ccaFileHandle);

end = clock();
loggers->GetLogger()->info("End time is " + to_string(end));
loggers->GetLogger()->info("Total time is " + to_string(double(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SECOND));
```

As the code shows, the files are all destroyed before calculating the time.
The strange thing is that the total time is calculated but the written process is still ongoing.
I monitor the disk written details which stores the files
The write speed is not 0(I close all executables which could write data to disk) and I am sure the write is not finished yet.

Does anyone meet this scenario before?

Comment: File writes are not committed to disk synchronously, unless you go to great lengths to bypass the OS's default file caching/buffering.

Comment: @dxiv What do you mean not synchronous? File read speed and file write speed are different which cause read process is done and the write process is still ongoing? If so. where did the data store, in the RAM? I forgot to mention the data size is 18 GB. Actually the file write takes almost 15min(20MB/s), the total time is almost 4min like what I mentioned it takes less time. The file read speed is faster than file write.

Comment: Read vs write speed is not what matters here. Point is that both work with the system file cache, not with the physical disk directly. See [File Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-caching),  [FlushFileBuffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-flushfilebuffers) and [FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#caching-behavior).